# Python 3.5: Calculating the mean for a list section that matches a for loop criteria

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have multiple lists of data and one of which is a list of `datetime.datetime` objects that I want to use in a `for` loop to calculate subsections of other lists. What I am really doing is converting subhourly measurements to daily measurements but cannot get a single mean number for the entire day with my loop function

For example:

```
mean = []
for i in range(len(date)):
    if date[i].day == date[i+1].day:
        mean.append(np.mean(number[i:i+1])
```

But this doesn't take the mean for all numbers in number under that day

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: you want to calculate mean between days ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the a single mean value from the looping function. I was hoping to get a single mean from all the numbers that match the dates in the if statement. I guess basically: How can I calculate the mean for a specific section of my list? Each section is a day, so a daily mean

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with the date as the key function to divide your list of numbers into sections with the same date, and then calculate the mean for each section.